# Hibernate doesn't passes generated id

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have issue with mapping using hibernate.
Two tables matrix and matrix_value.
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE matrix (
  matrix_id      INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  number_of_rows INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  number_of_cols INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (matrix_id)
)  ENGINE =InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE matrix_value (
  id         INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  matrix_id  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  row_id     INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column_id  INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  matrix_val INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_matrix_value_matrix
  FOREIGN KEY (matrix_id) REFERENCES matrix (matrix_id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)  ENGINE =InnoDB;
```

After generating of matrix_values and inserting matrix rows and columns it
must automatically take matrix_id and pass it to the matrix_values, but it throws

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'matrix_id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

**Also it adds to the table 'matrix' additional column 'matrixValues' filled with null.**

Here is method

```
 public void fillMatrixWithValues(MatrixValue[] values) throws Exception {        
    Session session = HibernateUtils.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        if (values != null && values.length != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                session.saveOrUpdate(values[i]);
            }
            tx.commit();
        }       
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        logger.error("Error fillMatrixWithValues-method: " + e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }     finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**Matrix (POJO)**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "matrix_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int matrixId;

@Column(name = "number_of_rows", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int numberOfRows;

@Column(name = "number_of_cols", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int numberOfCols;

@OneToMany (mappedBy= "matrix", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Transient
private List<MatrixValue> values;
```

**MatrixValues (POJO)**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@Column(name = "matrix_id", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private int matrixId;

@Column(name = "row_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int rowId;

@Column(name = "column_id", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int columnId;

@Column(name = "matrix_val", unique = false, nullable = false)
private int value;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "matrix_id")
private Matrix matrix;

getters and setters
```

**hibernate.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/matrixbase</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>

        <mapping class="kuidin.task5.entity.Matrix" />
        <mapping class="kuidin.task5.entity.MatrixValue" />
<hibernate-configuration>
```

What is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the error deals with a Constraint (that only resides in MATRIX_VALUES), it seems that when the `saveOrUpdate` is called, the `matrix_id` is not populated. Have you looked at whatever is creating `MatrixValue[] values` and ensure it is populated it? If so, please add that code as well.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well, I'm sure, that **MatrixValue[] values** is   populated. It is shown on my jsp. And each 'value' has matrix_id=0. And after inserting in has to have 'matrix_id' euqaled to id of Matrix entity. In jdbc it was done with help of get_generated_id. In hibernate i've added this property.

Comment: Sorry, I meant whatever is creating `values` that it is populating the `matrixId` field. Weird that it is always the same value

Comment: Sorry, maybe i do not understand something. If i'm creating new MatrixValue all fields equal to '0'. Then id - autoincremented and  while inserting values it has to take from Matrix it's 'matrix_id' with annotation @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Transient and the matrix_id field (with annotations) in the MatrixValues class. You don't need either.

Explanation:

1. the matrixValues collection is not transient. It should be persisted, although the Matrix is not the 'owner' of the association (when persisting Hibernate will look at the mapped field to find the value to store, although this should yield the same value) this is called the 'inverse' side of the (bi-directional) association.
2. the matrix_id column in the matrixValues will be filled with the id of the matrix assigned to the matrix field. Adding the additional field is superfluous and annotating it as @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is just dead wrong: the column is not part of the primary key of the table that contains it.

Comment: How I'll get values from **matrix_values** table if i'll delete  the matrix_id field in the MatrixValues class? Now I have method  **MatrixValue[] getValuesById(int matrixId)** where **values = session.createQuery("from MatrixValue values where values.matrixId=" + matrixId).list();** Without matrix_id it doesn't work. Then how I have to annotate fields? Soory, i'm new one in hibernate.

Comment: Well, the collection of matrix values in the matrix is loaded eagerly, so you can just fetch the matrix by its id and get the values by accessing the collection.

Comment: Yes, I tried. But not everywhere this approach is suitable.